# Inner join and and set text when value is one using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to inner join FaxType and IsPackage into one column. once the columns have been inner joined i would like to add the word "Package" only if IsPackage = 1.

- the RX comes from the "FaxType table"
- Package comes from the IsPackage table.
- packagetype is the temp column. I am not sure if i need this?

example of expected result

```
 packagetype = RX, Package
```

Query:

```
select 'DM' as FaxType, FaxId,  RequestDate, FaxedTo, FaxNumber, Status, ExtendedStatus, StatusDate, UserName, IsPackage, DocumentId, -1 as PatientMedicationId, '' as Event, '-1' as NCPDPID, 0 as IsEPerscription, -1 as AccessionNumber, 
    Case When IsPackage = 0 then (Select FilePath from PatientDocument where DocumentId = fl.DocumentId and ( '443' = -1 or '443' = PatientId )) else (Select FilePath from dm_Package where fl.DocumentId = PackageId and ( '443' = -1 or '443' = PatientId )) End as Path, 
    Case When IsPackage = 0 then (Select LastFirstName from Patient p, PatientDocument pd where fl.DocumentId = pd.DocumentId and pd.PatientId = p.PatientId) else (select LastFirstName from Patient p, dm_Package pa where fl.DocumentId = pa.PackageId and pa.PatientId = p.PatientId) END 
    as LastFirstName, Case When IsPackage = 0 then (select [Description] from PatientDocument where fl.DocumentId = DocumentId and ( '443' = -1 or '443' = PatientId )) else (select PackageName from dm_Package where fl.DocumentId = PackageId and ( '443' = -1 or '443' = PatientId )) End  
    as [Description], '' as JobId, -1 as SeqNumber, '' as RefNumber, (select DocId from dbo.PatientDocument pd where fl.DocumentId = pd.DocumentId) as DocId
FROM         dbo.dm_FaxLog fl
```

Comment: Can you describe the two tables in a little more detail? Show some sample data. Or, better yet, create a sqlfiddle at http://http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case When IsPackage = 1 then 'DM, Package' else 'DM' end as FaxType